# django_rest_framework, how to update user profile by token?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have models user and profile(foreight key to user).
Can someone show me(or explain) example how in viewset, update user profile by token. 
I send token in HTTP header that name is: "Authorization", and value: "Token " + (token_string).

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Profileerializer

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        # Get user by token and update profile
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you said, I'll asume that you are using [Django Rest Framework Token Authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)

If so,

> The request.user property will typically be set to an instance of the contrib.auth package's User class.
>
> The request.auth property is used for any additional authentication information, for example, it may be used to represent an authentication token that the request was signed with.

That way, you should be able to do something like:

```
def update(self, request, pk=None):
    user = request.user
    profile = user.profile
    # Update with user here
```

Comment: Please, if the answer solves your problem choose it as the selected answer so others can find it easily. Thanks!